# Properties of dynamical only seen in degree 3 or higher

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

A classical result of dynamical systems states that the solution to an ODE of degree 1 cannot be oscillatory.

So is there a qualitative property of in dynamical systems of degree 3 that cannot happen in degree 2? Is there a generalization of this (something that only happens from degree n)?

Comment: A solution in 2D can't be ***chaotic***. And no, I don't think one can generalize that. More dimensions don't bring much of anything.

Comment: By "degree" do you mean "order"?

Comment: Motion in $n$ dimensions is a particular case of motion in $n+1$ dimensions. Therefore a property of motion in $n$ dimensions is a possible property of motion in all higher dimensions.